# Ambiguous type arising from try

Tags: haskell

I am trying to do a little error handling when opening a file, to be sure that the file exists/is readable. Here's my attempt :

```
init struct = do
    str <- try $ readFile (filePath struct)
    case str of
        Left exception -> print exception
        Right content -> execute content struct
```

(Struct is a data structure where I keep my file path and other variables).
I get this error:

> Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘try’
> prevents the constraint ‘(Exception a0)’ from being solved.
> Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.

But I just don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

it's because the result of `try :: ... -> IO (Either e a)` has a type-parameter for the exception `e` and you just put this into `print` which can handle all sort of stuff (as long as the `e` is in `Show`) - so it's not obvious to the compiler what type the intermediate `e` needs to be.

This is very similar to `show . read` - that should have type `String -> String` but what is `read` supposed to do? Read a `Int`, a `Float` - something different?

---

Easiest way to fix this is IMO with an type-application:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

init struct = do
    str <- try @IOException $ readFile (filePath struct)
    case str of
        Left exception -> print exception
        Right content -> execute content struct
```

Of course you can add the *type annotation* wherever you want:

```
str <- try $ readFile (filePath struct) :: IO (Either IOException MyStruct)
```

etc.

Comment: Ah well I didn't know type-applications existed, thank you.I actually am not trying to print the exception but call another function to exit the program if anything goes wrong with the readFile, adding the type annotation works great. Thank you !

Comment: `SomeException` is overkill, IMO, and even [the docs do not recommend it](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#g:4): it includes division by zero, user Ctrl-C, and several other exceptions one usually does not want to handle. In this context `IOException` looks more sensible.

Comment: sure - I'll happily change it

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Carsten, it's very clear now ! I'm always learning something new about Haskell everyday